# How many lattice points are on a the line segment connecting $(a, 0)$ and $(0, d)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How many lattice points are on a the line segment connecting $(a, 0)$ and $(0, d)$, where $\{a, d\} \in \mathbb{Z}$?  I found the slope for the problem but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Are $a,d$ known to be integers?  Have you tried small numbers, like $a=2,d=5$ and $a=3,d=6$?  You might get some inspiration.

Comment: I do not know what a and d are. They could be anything as far as I know.

Comment: I would be surprised if $a,d$ are permitted to be non-integer.  I suggest you solve it for integers first.  If they are not integers it will be rare to hit a lattice point at all.  If you solve the integer case, you can use it to think about the non-integer case.

Comment: they are integers

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a hint with a specific example. (Assuming $a,d$ are integers.)

Let's take $(4,0)$ and $(0,6)$. The lattice points are the points where the two coordinates are also integers.

The lattice points are $(4,0), (2,3), (0,6)$.

Can you try from here?

Comment: No I still do not understand. I know the slope of the question is -d/a but I do not know how many lattice points there are.

Comment: @DHGamer:  draw the picture for this example and my $a=3,d=6$.  You can reduce the slope to lower terms in both cases.  How does the lowest term version of the slope show up on the drawing?

Comment: I suggest you try a few more pairs of integers. Get out some graph paper and count the lattice points. You'll get more out of the exercise (and it will be more satisfying) if you come up with the answer yourself. Give yourself some more credit. ;) Having said that ... look at the greatest common factor of $4$ and $6$ to see how that plays into things.

Comment: you get a slope of -1/2

Comment: the x goes up by 2 and the greatest comman factor is 2.

Comment: That's right. Now try some more points. Do you see a relation between the number of lattice points and the GCF?

Comment: the slope for this one is 2/3 and the middle point is 2,3

Comment: I understand how to get the points when there are not variables but know that there are what do i do?

Comment: You have to 1) go from $0$ to $4$ (= $4 \to 0$) and from $0$ to $6$ in integral steps 2) the number of steps shall be the same 3) you are looking for the maximum of such common number (to catch all the integral points in between) 4) adjust to include (or not) the end-points.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, everyone. I really appreciate it.